# How to resize a Win32 listbox to fit its content?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, autoresize

Is there any way to resize a Win32 listbox to fit its content (the minimum size that will show all its content, not needing a scrollbar), whenever its items change?

Thank!

**Edit: I need resize both width and height of listbox.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify whether you wanted horizontal as well as vertical, but I'm going to assume not. Basically, you need to get the number of items and the item height and multiply them, then add on the space for the control borders (unless the control is borderless, you may need to play around with this):

```
void AutosizeListBox(HWND hWndLB)
{
    int iItemHeight = SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0, 0);
    int iItemCount = SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);

    // calculate new desired client size
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWndLB, &rc);
    rc.bottom = rc.top + iItemHeight * iItemCount;

    // grow for borders
    rc.right += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;
    rc.bottom += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;

    // resize
    SetWindowPos(hWndLB, 0, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

If you want horizontal sizing as well you would need to select the right font into a DC, and loop through all the items to calculate the maximum text length using `GetTextExtentPoint32`.

EDIT: Added a version that calculates horizontal size as well.

```
void AutosizeListBox(HWND hWndLB)
{
    int iItemHeight = SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0, 0);
    int iItemCount = SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);

    // get a DC and set up the font
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWndLB);
    HGDIOBJ hOldFont = SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)SendMessage(hWndLB, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0));

    // calculate width of largest string
    int iItemWidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iItemCount; i++)
    {
        int iLen = SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETTEXTLEN, i, 0);
        TCHAR* pBuf = new TCHAR[iLen + 1];
        SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETTEXT, i, (LPARAM)pBuf);

        SIZE sz;
        GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, pBuf, iLen, &sz);
        if (iItemWidth < sz.cx) iItemWidth = sz.cx;

        delete[] pBuf;
    }

    SelectObject(hDC, hOldFont);
    ReleaseDC(hWndLB, hDC);

    // calculate new desired client size
    RECT rc;
    SetRect(&rc, 0, 0, iItemWidth, iItemHeight * iItemCount);

    // grow for borders
    rc.right += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;
    rc.bottom += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;

    // resize
    SetWindowPos(hWndLB, 0, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Comment: And note this will only work for single-column listboxes; if you're using a multiple column listbox as you describe in your other question then the method would be different.

Comment: indeed, I need both size, as this listbox work as a tooltip option for a textbox.

Comment: @TuyenTk: can you confirm single or multiple column?

Comment: it is single column, and all items is plain text. This is not a custom ListBox

Comment: One method I'm thinking is measure size of each item's text and get the max value, plus a few extra pixel

Comment: @TuyenTk: I've edited my answer with an example of how to do that. You might need to play around and add a bit of extra space (I haven't actually tested this).

Comment: Thank for your help! It worked great! I add few more pixel to `iItemWidth` for space on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the flags! Was using `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`, but even though `SetWindowPos` succeeded, the LV's co-ordinates never changed!