# MFC (C++): how to set the width of ListBox as designed?

Tags: winapi, mfc, listbox

I am following this link to set the height of ListBox dynamically ([How to resize a Win32 listbox to fit its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039075/how-to-resize-a-win32-listbox-to-fit-its-content)). However, at the same time I want to keep the width fixed (i.e. values as originally specified in rc). But I don't know how to retrieve the value and set the width.

Comment: Actually the post you are referenced also provides solution for the ListBox width calculation. Did you tried the second implementation of the **void AutosizeListBox(HWND hWndLB)** function? The code is located under `EDIT: Added a version that calculates horizontal size as well`.

Comment: @Jackdaw, If I understand correctly, does it depend on the number of characters? What I need is fixed width as determined by the design.

Comment: The **AutosizeListBox(HWND hWndLB)** function calculates a width according to the largest string in the ListBox to respect the current font used by the ListBox. The number of characters is not so important, that's how long the line is, given the current font.

Comment: There are two versions of the function in that post. The first one only changes the height of the control. The second changes width and height.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, The first version also changes the width. I try to comment out the line of "rc.right += ...", but the width still changes and doesn't match with the design.

Comment: OK, I solve by adding another SM_CXVSCROLL to rc.right.

Comment: Hi, if you have solved this issue, please feel free to add as an answer and mark yourself, to help people with the same issue.

Comment: If you want to use the width of a control declared in a resource script, simply don't change it at runtime. It's not obvious to me, why you are resizing a control that you do not wish to resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want to achieve is to adjust the height of a ListBox according to the number of items while keeping the width fixed as specified in the design. I pretty much follow the solution here ([How to resize a Win32 listbox to fit its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039075/how-to-resize-a-win32-listbox-to-fit-its-content)). It changes the height but modifies the width as well which is not acceptable.

The following lines adjust the width by taking into account of scroll bar width which fixes the issue.

```
    rc.right += (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2);
+   if ((list.GetStyle() & WS_VSCROLL) != 0)
+       rc.right += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
```

Alternatively as suggested in comments,

```
-   rc.right += (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2);
    rc.bottom += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;

+   RECT window_rc;
+   ::GetWindowRect(hWndLB, &window_rc);

    // resize
-   ::SetWindowPos(hWndLB, 0, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
+   ::SetWindowPos(hWndLB, 0, 0, 0, window_rc.right - window_rc.left, rc.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Comment: Just call `GetWindowRect` and keep the width in your call to `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: @IInspectable, I replace GetClientRect with GetWindowRect, it doesn't work right. The width is much bigger.

Comment: The width is calculated as `right - left`. If that's *"much bigger"*, you likely fumbled the math.

Comment: @IInspectable, Yes you are right. It works and I modify the answer accordingly. Thank you for the help!